# Android Usage of /system/priv-app Directory

Tags: android

I am testing installation of pre-installed apps in Android. The directory `/system/priv-app` allows APKs inside to be granted system permissions, regardless of the app signature.

Although app signature is ignored, I want to ask if anyone knows any real cases where a vendor (like Samsung) put a third party app (third party signature) inside the `priv-app` folder, just so that the app is granted system permissions. Additionally, is it the case that in practice, vendors only tend to put apps signed with their key into this folder, and the signature ignorance aspect is not utilized.

Comment: It's common in the U.S. for each major operator to have their own custom version of Android that contains many extra apps installed as System Apps that are specific to that operator (AT&T, Verizon, Sprint, T-Mobile), and many of them are actually written by third-party software vendors.